# Trying to style browse button inside file field

Tags: html, css, forms, file-upload

I've looked at some similar stack overflow questions but none have helped.  I have a file field that looks like this:

[image: File field]

I am trying to mvd the location of the browse button to the left so it aligns with the text fieldand add a border-radius to it so it matches the text field around it.  I can't figure out how to do it.  Here is the html for the file field:

```
<input class="field file-field" type="file" multiple="multiple"></input>
```

And here is the css:

```
.field {  
    float:left; 
    display:inline; 
    width:150px; 
    height:28px;padding:0 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    border: solid 1px #bfbfbf; 
    background: url(/assets/field30.png); 
    color:#575757; 
    font-size:13px;  
    margin: 0 10px 0 40px; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    font-weight:300; 
}

.file-field {  
    width:500px; 
    border-radius: 25px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear what you are asking, as we can't see what you are trying to align with, but if you remove the height setting from the field and perhaps use padding all around you will get better results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">

.field {   
    width:150px; 
    padding:5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    border: solid 1px #bfbfbf; 
    background: url(/assets/field30.png); 
    color:#575757; 
    font-size:13px;  
    margin: 0 10px 0 40px; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    font-weight:300; 
}

.file-field {  
    width:500px; 
    border-radius: 25px;   
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
    <input class="field file-field" type="file" multiple="multiple"></input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```